# why latex templates downloaded from latextemplates.com not working in my tex editor?

Tags: templates, kile

I downloaded templates from latextemplates.com and opened them in texeditor and kile and while compiling it gives so many errors but I am able to compile them online on share latex website.Can anyone help?

Comment: 'ello, [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `:)` Do you have an updated TeX distro?

Comment: sorry man but what exactly is TeX distro? @PauloCereda

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please tell us more about the errors you get. Chances are your TeX system is not completely installed. Kile has the ability to check your TeX installation, what do you get there?

Comment: welcome! have a look at [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @cmhughes my update manager shows all software are up to date

Answer (score 1):

The templates from http://www.latextemplates.com require updated `TeX` distributions because of all the dependencies on various packages.  Download the entire `TeX` distribution and install it (be sure to read the instructions regarding uninstalling older versions, etc.)  Ensure all of the packages are installed and on the current versions.

Comment: and how do I download these tex distributions? @Kevin

Comment: Edited: The Kile distribution is located at http://kile.sourceforge.net/ Simply reinstall it fresh with the latest version (if you're not already running it).  It's helpful to also post a copy of the errors you're receiving.  The Legrand Orange Book template, for example, doesn't work with \frontmatter, so the problem could like in either outdated distributions or incompatibility.

Comment: @amitoz Also try TeXLive http://www.latex-project.org/ftp.html for your OS.

Comment: well I am using ubuntu12.04 Lts and downloaded kile and tex maker from software centre , i hope that wouldn;t be the issue? @Kevin

Comment: @amitoz I recommend that you post your distribution version, the template you're using, and the errors that you're receiving so the community can better analyse your situation.

Comment: @amitoz, as 12.04 is already over a year ago, it is possible the package manager doesn't contain the newest version available on the web...  you can probably find the version number in the help->about menu...